# Why will my Lambda function not receive event data when it is called from CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I have a CodePipeline that I built to deploy a Go application, and now I'm trying to make it apply database migrations using golang-migrate.  I have a Lambda function written in Go to apply the migrations, but when it is called from CodePipeline, it does not receive the event data with the revision location, user parameters, etc.  For simplicity, I removed the migration code and replaced it with code to simply write the event data to CloudWatch:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func Handler(ctx context.Context, job events.CodePipelineJob) (string, error) {    
    fmt.Printf("%#v", job)    
    return "Success", nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

When the CodePipeline runs, it triggers the function, and I find the following log in CloudWatch from the fmt.Printf statement in the function:

events.CodePipelineJob{ID:"", AccountID:"", Data:events.CodePipelineData{ActionConfiguration:events.CodePipelineActionConfiguration{Configuration:events.CodePipelineConfiguration{FunctionName:"", UserParameters:""}}, InputArtifacts:[]events.CodePipelineInputArtifact(nil), OutPutArtifacts:[]events.CodePipelineOutputArtifact(nil), ArtifactCredentials:events.CodePipelineArtifactCredentials{SecretAccessKey:"", SessionToken:"", AccessKeyID:""}, ContinuationToken:""}}

The job parameter is an empty object and is not being bound to the CodePipeline event data like I would expect.  All the research I have done indicates that it should receive the CodePipelineJob event defined here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/blob/master/events/codepipeline_job.go

I have confirmed that the expected JSON event format is received if I use a Python Lambda function:

```
import json
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def main(event, context):    
    logger.info("Event: " + str(event))

    return "Success"
```

When I change the CodePipeline to call the Python function instead, an event containing the correct data is successfully written to CloudWatch.  It looks similar to this:

```
{
   "CodePipeline.job":{
      "id":"11111111-abcd-1111-abcd-111111abcdef",
      "accountId":"111111111111",
      "data":{
         "actionConfiguration":{
            "configuration":{
               "FunctionName":"MyLambdaFunctionForAWSCodePipeline",
               "UserParameters":"some-input-such-as-a-URL"
            }
         },
         "inputArtifacts":[
            {
               "location":{
                  "s3Location":{
                     "bucketName":"the name of the bucket configured as the pipeline artifact store in Amazon S3, for example codepipeline-us-east-2-1234567890",
                     "objectKey":"the name of the application, for example CodePipelineDemoApplication.zip"
                  },
                  "type":"S3"
               },
               "revision":null,
               "name":"ArtifactName"
            }
         ],
         "outputArtifacts":[            
         ],
         "continuationToken":"A continuation token if continuing job",
         "encryptionKey":{
            "id":"arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:111122223333:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab",
            "type":"KMS"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So, my question is, why will my Python Lambda function write the event when my Go function will not?  Is there something wrong with the way I defined the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong event type for the input parameter.  When I changed the parameter type to events.CodePipelineEvent, the function started correctly logging the event details.  The root JSON element in the input event is named CodePipeline.job.  The events.CodePipelineEvent struct is defined like this:

```
CodePipelineEvent struct {
    CodePipelineJob CodePipelineJob `json:"CodePipeline.job"`
}
```

Once I switched the parameter to the correct type, it started correctly matching the root element and pulling in the values.  Here is the updated function:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func Handler(ctx context.Context, event events.CodePipelineEvent) (string, error) {
    fmt.Printf("%#v", event)
    return "Success", nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```